# Various link on the same image using mapping

Tags: html, hyperlink, navigation, mapping

I have a single image with various tabs for navigation as shown :-

[image: my navigation image]

I want that i use the same image to point to different link either by using mapping or some coordinates.

Can anyone help me through code to do so ???

OR any link will do the job.

Thanks in advance :) :)

Comment: i want the same image to point to different links when clicked to different places....

Comment: I made one for you with CSS and your image, i only added two links, but i think you get the idea. Much easier than imagemaps. http://jsfiddle.net/qQjBf/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use map

sample:

```
<img src=ur_image usemap="#linkmap">

<map name="linkmap">

    <area shape="rect" coords="x1,y1,x2,y2" href="url_1" />

    <area shape="rect" coords="some other coords" href="url_2" />

    <area shape="rect" coords="some other coords" hhref="url_3" />
</map>
```

where (x1,y1) is a coord of top left vertex of the rectangle 1 ("home tab") and (x2,y2) is bottom right vertex of the same rectangle. and so on for all the rectangles there.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest using CSS Sprites instead of image mapping? If not, then inform me, so that we make it work together?

Image map has many usages, and one of the most important usage is to mark some hot points on a map (an image) so that user can click on that part and go to another page. 
But developers and designers used it a while ago to create navigational menus, and why? Let's see.
When you use 10 images in your document, browsers sends 10 requests to the server to get those 10 images. This is like your mom sending you to kitchen 10 times to bring 10 spoons one by one (imagine that!). Many designers use background images for menu items. So if a menu has 5 items, they usually use 5 * 3 = 15 background images (1 for normal state, 1 for hover, and 1 for selected, per menu item). This means a burden on the web site, lower load time, more server traffic and many more problems.
Therefore they used image maps to load an image once, and divide it in client-side to clickable parts to navigate user to desired pages. 
But the same effect could be used with a technique known as `CSS Sprites`. In this technique, those 15 image are bundled into 1 image and in client-side, by using CSS for each item, only a portion of that image is shown. It's like your mom asking you to go to kitchen to bring 15 spoons in a bundle.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use an [Image map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the map tag. Here's an example:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap

Comment: hmm... thats nice...:) But can you tell me what those 4 coordinates for rectangle represent ? (u,v,w,x). I mean what do they represent on my image ??

Comment: @Prashant check my answer, i have explained what those 4 coords mean.

Answer (score 1):

Make an unordered list full of list elements. Display them as inline-blocks. Give each list a background-image, background-width,height and position to get the correct image part in it, and then enclose the list item in a link.

Really, just don't use an imagemap. You'll regret it.

Edit: Here's a [link showing how it's done.](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-css-menu-using-image-sprites)

Edit again: [Here, i made it for you.](http://jsfiddle.net/qQjBf/6)